# Perform shell command (ls) on other directroy using exec() in cpp

Tags: c++, linux, shell, operating-system

I want to cout the directories/files at the home directory using exec system call. What I am unable to understand is where can I specify on which directory ls should be applied.
Here is what i have tried:

```
cout<<execle("/bin/ls","bin/ls",NULL);
```

It prints the files in the current directory.
I treid passing path as environment variable but that doesn't helps either. Perhaps that is used to specify where to find the executable file of passed to execl,

```
         char *env2[]={"PATH=/home/username", NULL};
         cout<<execle("/bin/ls","bin/ls",NULL, env2);
```

I though changing the directory before calling execl would help but, couldn't find easy way to do that.
How can i specify the directory on which ls should be performed.
Note: I am using ubuntu linux

Comment: See `man ls`: `ls` allows you to specify the directory you want to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using execvp()

```
cout << execvp("ls", ["ls", "/home/username"])
```

execvp takes as its argument the command you are attempting to execute, and as its second a list including the command and a list of arguments given to the command being executed.

Comment: Thanks! Needed to change syntax a bit but it was helpful,         char *arg[]={"/bin/ls", "/home/username", NULL};
        cout << execvp("/bin/ls", arg);

Comment: Sorry about that! And no problem, if you found that my answer resolved your question please consider accepting it as a solution :)